# Функция без пролога и эпилога

Tags: c, ассемблер

Каким образом задать функцию без пролога и эпилога так, чтобы создавался только код тела?

Например, чтобы функция

```
void func() {
    __asm__ volatile__ ("nop");
}
```

компилировалась в код

```
0:  90                      nop
```

вместо кода

```
0:  55                      push   %ebp
1:  89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
3:  90                      nop
4:  5d                      pop    %ebp
5:  c3                      ret
```

Есть ли стандартные средства C (visual c, gcc) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В стандарте C нет такой возможности. Она может предоставляться конкретными компиляторами. Например, для Visual C++ на платформе x86 это будет выглядеть так:

```
__declspec( naked ) void func( void ) { __asm { nop } }
```

Для ARM gcc:

```
void func() __attribute__ ((naked));

void func(void) {
    __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
}
```